# Java export missing from Selenium IDE 1.0.9

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium.  I am using Firefox and trying to export the test case out to a Java file, but the option for Java is missing from the menu.  Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest Selenium version is 1.0.9.

Click Options / Format and then any of JUnit3 / JUnit4 / TestNG.

These will export Java test cases which you can easily run inside Netbeans.

The code extends SeleneseTestCase (which extends the normal JUnit TestCase).

Answer (score 0):

You have to download selenium Ide new Version, download selenium new version from the link given below
http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Open Selenium iDE.
File > Export test cast > choose the language in which do you want to convert
http://screencast.com/t/ZrfGQbGZFLTj